# How to represent a collection of objects

Tags: collections, diagram

I need to make some drawing to explain programming logic at the whiteboard.

I often need to manipulate collections of objects.

Which symbol can I use to visually show a collection ?

I wish to have an example for better understanding, because I was told to use aggregation/composition in UML style, but I don't really see it. For instance, if I want to represent a collection of Object ABC...

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an established symbology, or do you just ad hoc your drawings? Usually, I'd go for an [entity-relationship diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Er_diagram) with a crow's-foot going from the collection entity to the contained objects, [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language), or whatever the people I'm talking to understand. That last part is usually the key...!

Comment: Even if I agree, the most important is to be understood, I'm wondering if there are universal symbols for collection (as for a DB).
Do you have an example of the representation you mention ?

Comment: Not even an arrow is a truly culture-independent symbol... Take a look at the WP links.

Comment: Sure. I was asking for an example, coz in the WP I can't see a sample of collection representation, and I'm not sure to fully understand your suggestion. :)